# VideoView Completion Listener inside a dialog box in Android

Tags: android, dialog, android-videoview

I want to play a video file in videoview which is displayed inside a dialog and on completion the dialog box should be closed . I read about doing it through media controller so I have the following:

```
final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(MyActivity.this);
    dialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    dialog.setContentView(R.layout.MyCustomLayoutWithVideoView);
    dialog.show();
    WindowManager.LayoutParams lp = new WindowManager.LayoutParams(
    WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    lp.copyFrom(dialog.getWindow().getAttributes());
    dialog.getWindow().setAttributes(lp);
    final VideoView videoview = (VideoView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.videoView);
    Uri uri = Uri.parse(SoundFile);

    **MediaController mc = new MediaController(this);
    videoview.setMediaController(mc);**

        videoview.start();

    videoview.setVideoURI(uri);
    videoview.setOnCompletionListener(new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener() {

        @Override
        public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) 
{
Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Msg", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    });
```

1) The part of declaring mediacontroller is wrong.. it cant get context, what is the context?

2) How can control this dialog's size based on the maximum height and weight?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use getApplicationContext() to get context. Context represents the environment data. Take a look here: [What is Context in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3572463/what-is-context-in-android)

Comment: I typed MediaController mediaController = new MediaController(this);
        mediaController.setAnchorView(videoview);
        videoview.setMediaController(mediaController); and it is working.. which is same!?! How about the dialog's size

Comment: in order to change the size you could set de maxWidth, maxHeight of the MyCustomLayoutWithVideoView xml parent layout